# Dickey Fuller Test shows significance but the mean is not constant

Tags: python, arima

I'm trying to examine whether my timeseries is stationary using Dickey Fuller Test. Looking at my raw data, I'm quite sure that they are not stationary. However, after implementing Dickey Fuller Test on my data using python, the results show that my timeseries is sationary (with a very low p-value).

My code and the results are as follow:

```
def test_stationarity(timeseries):

    #Determing rolling statistics
    rolmean = timeseries.rolling(window=7,center=False).mean()
    rolstd = timeseries.rolling(window=7,center=False).std()

    #Plot rolling statistics:
    orig = plt.plot(timeseries, color='blue',label='Original')
    mean = plt.plot(rolmean, color='red', label='Rolling Mean')
    std = plt.plot(rolstd, color='black', label = 'Rolling Std')
    plt.legend(loc='best')
    plt.title('Rolling Mean & Standard Deviation')
    #plt.savefig('stationarity_{}.png'.format(timeseries.columns.values[0]))
    #plt.show(block=False)

    #Perform Dickey-Fuller test:
    print ('Results of Dickey-Fuller Test:')
    dftest = adfuller(timeseries.values.ravel(), autolag='AIC')
    dfoutput = pd.Series(dftest[0:4], index=['Test Statistic','p-value','#Lags Used','Number of Observations Used'])
    for key,value in dftest[4].items():
        dfoutput['Critical Value (%s)'%key] = value
    print (dfoutput)
```

[The data is a timesries of physical cross-border electricity flow between Germany and France in hourly time-frame. Negative values indicate electricity flow from Germany to France](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvoNJ.png)

```
Results of Dickey-Fuller Test:
Test Statistic                -7.252678e+00
p-value                        1.763304e-10
Lags Used                      4.600000e+01
Number of Observations Used    2.031600e+04
Critical Value (1%)           -3.430672e+00
Critical Value (5%)           -2.861682e+00
Critical Value (10%)          -2.566846e+00
```

Can someone please explain me how come this is possible? Is there any assumption to use the Dickey Fuller test?

Comment: This looks like a question for [stats.se], not [so].

Comment: Thanks @Chris! I'm quite new here and still learning where to post. Now I found the answer on Stackexchange :)

Comment: Hi @Nick, can you please pass the link to the answer you found?